# Responsive design: centering a title inside an li with 2 other li's each side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need a little help over here please :)

I have this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/eyTYF/

Just an `ul` with 5 `li's`, all with `a` tag's inside.

And I want all these elements fill 100% of the width of the screen, the icons maintains its size (50px) and just the title differentiates the size.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to do this with `display: table`. http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/lbBKx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

ul {list-style: none; padding-left: 0; width: 100%; display: table;}

li {display: table-cell;}

li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(5){
    width: 50px;
}

li{line-height: 50px;text-align: center;}

li:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
}

li:nth-child(2){
    background: green;
}

li:nth-child(3){
    background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(4){
    background: green;
}

li:nth-child(5){
    background: red;
}

a{color: white; display: block; width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 50px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 1</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 2</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Title</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 3</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 4</i></a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was very straight and easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to change the markup a little...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 1</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 2</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 3</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i>Icon 4</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Title</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
ul {list-style: none; padding-left: 0; width: 100%;}
li{height: 50px;text-align: center;}
li:nth-child(1){
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(2){
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
li:nth-child(5){
    background: blue;
clear: none

}
li:nth-child(4){
    background: green;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
li:nth-child(3){
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
a{color: white; display: block; width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 50px;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3ufR/

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to set the middle `<li>` a width of 100% and then subtract 50px for each icon. You must set the `z-index` to put the middle div behind the others.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eyTYF/2/)!

The code results in:

```
    li {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center; 
        position:relative;         /*To make z-index work*/
        z-index:1
}

    li:nth-child(3){
        background: blue;
        width:100%;                  
        margin: 0 -100px 0 -100px;   /* Subtract 100px for each side */
        position:relative;           /*To make z-index work*/
        z-index:0
    }
```